# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Java version

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, classnotfound

I want to run a .jar file but i keep coming with this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/extl/jade/user/ExtilityException
    at org.dasein.cloud.flexiant.compute.FlexComputeServices.getVirtualMachineSupport(FlexComputeServices.java:24)
    at org.dasein.cloud.flexiant.compute.FlexComputeServices.getVirtualMachineSupport(FlexComputeServices.java:17)
    at com.ics.multicloud.LaunchServer.launch(LaunchServer.java:130)
    at com.ics.multicloud.LaunchServer.main(LaunchServer.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.extl.jade.user.ExtilityException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 4 more
```

Can you please give me any ideas?
I think there is something wrong with my java version.

My java version is

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.10.5.el5_9-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

and javac is also

```
javac 1.7.0_25
```

Comment: looks like a classpath issue... Not enough information to help you :)

Comment: Didn't set Class Path in manifest.  Nothing wrong w/ Java; it's you and your code.

Comment: Should i set a classpath ?

Answer (score 0):

If the class `com.extl.jade.user.ExtilityException` is not provided inside the jar file, you must add to the classpath where is the corresponding `.class` or jar container.

If you have the error while invoking java with `java -jar` you can test a correct classpath with `java -cp your_first_jar;your_other_jar your.main.class.to.start`

You can later add the jar to you `CLASSPATH` environment variable but it is not mandatory, fixing the `-cp` setting can be enough.